# Find index of Fibonacci Sequence with x digits (Project Euler Problem 25)

Tags: python, algorithm

This is my code, it works pretty well. I'm new to Python and programming in general. I wonder if this approach is okay... I saw this decorator in a video and I wonder if it's good practice to use it.

The problem: [Project Euler Problem 25](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25)

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        F = 1
    else:
        F = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    return F 

x = 1
while True:
    x += 1
    if len(str(fibonacci(x))) == 1000:
        print(x)
        break
```

Comment: Why haven't you used a simple, brute force solution?

Comment: It was too slow??

Comment: It isn't slow, but the brute force solution is marginally faster.

Comment: "Good practice" depends far more on your application than on the decorator.  You can see the effect on your Fibonacci execution times; you haven't described any other application.

Answer (score 2):

That's one way to do it, and I think it's fine.

There are other ways to compute Fibonacci numbers quickly, e.g.,
applying a fast exponentiation algorithm to the recurrence.

For this problem, you can also get all the way to closed form. The
Fibonacci number F(n) satisfies

> F(n) = ((1 + √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + ((1 − √5)/2)<sup>n</sup>.

The second term goes to zero exponentially fast, so we can ignore it
unless there is a Fibonacci number very close to 10<sup>999</sup> (there
isn't). The number F(n) has at least 1000 digits if and only if it's
greater than or equal to 10<sup>999</sup>, so we need to minimize F(n)
subject to

> F(n) ≥ 10<sup>999</sup>,

which holds if and only if

> log<sub>10</sub> F(n) ≥ 999,

which is approximately equivalent to

> log<sub>10</sub> ((1 + √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> ≥ 999,

which holds if and only if

> n log<sub>10</sub> ((1 + √5)/2) ≥ 999,

so we should be able to take

> n = ⌈999 / log<sub>10</sub> ((1 + √5)/2)⌉.

Answer (score 0):

your first line did´t run in my python interpreter,
if you like you can use the lru_cache:

Here an example from [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-functools-lru_cache/):

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time


# Function that computes Fibonacci
# numbers without lru_cache
def fib_without_cache(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib_without_cache(n-1) + fib_without_cache(n-2)
    
# Execution start time
begin = time.time()
fib_without_cache(30)

# Execution end time
end = time.time()

print("Time taken to execute the\
function without lru_cache is", end-begin)

# Function that computes Fibonacci
# numbers with lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize = 128)
def fib_with_cache(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib_with_cache(n-1) + fib_with_cache(n-2)
    
begin = time.time()
fib_with_cache(30)
end = time.time()

print("Time taken to execute the \
function with lru_cache is", end-begin)
```